# Bonjour IPV4 resolving

Tags: ios, bonjour

I am using bonjour service to identify the near by peers and get the ipaddress and port number. I am succsfully advertising my peer and browsing the near by peers. I am resolving the peer to get the ipaddress and port number once any near by peer found .

Since i need only IPV4 ipaddress, i am looking for the IPV4 format form the peer address(NSNetservice object). But some times it's giving IPV6 format only instead of IPV4 & IPV6 formats.
Is there any way to restrict the NSNetservice object to get only IPV4.

Answer (score 0):

More than likely an IPv4 address may not be available. From [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/NetServices/Articles/about.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002458-SW5)-

> **Note:** IPv6 link-local addressing is simpler than IPv4 link-local addressing,
>   and thus is more reliable. Because of this, it is important that your
>   app support IPv6.